# Lost Answer, new suggestions please

Tags: riddle

I wrote this riddle years ago while walking around a shopping center in Sydney and I didn't think to write the answer down. So taking all guesses on what the answer should be.

*When one is not sour, when one is quite sweet,

When one is not real if not brown and neat,

When one is still chocolate yet not chocolate at all,

What is one at that point when bland like a wall?*

Comment: Mockolate? Just had to get it out of my system. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is

> White chocolate

When one is not sour, when one is quite sweet

> Raw cocoa is sour-sweet or even bitter, but it's not raw cocoa but chocolate, sweet chocolate.

When one is not real if not brown and neat

> Some people (and maybe even many) don't consider white chocolate as a real chocolate, and it has some basis as white chocolate is made of cocoa butter rather than the actual cocoa.

When one is still chocolate yet not chocolate at all

> Even if white chocolate is not made of brown cocoa, it's still chocolate (in name and due to having a bit of cocoa in it, the cocoa butter)

What is one at that point when bland like a wall?

> White chocolate tends to have a milder (blander) chocolate taste in contrast to its brown siblings

Comment: Judging from my own tastes this is probably the most likely answer.

Answer (score 3):

I guess,  it is

> Coffee and it's seeds.

As,

> coffee, in its raw form (as seed/ unprocessed ) is sour, but when it is served, it tastes sweet(usually), it's a flavour of chocolate, and when not real (when not made into a beverage) not worth even using.

Comment: rot13(Pbssrr ol vgfrys qbrf abg gnfgr fjrrg vs lbh qba'g nqq fhtne be zvyx be jungrire gb znxr vg gnfgr fjrrg..)